# How to parse Resume(Word doc) using Tika parser, Resumes have different format

Tags: apache-tika

I want to parse resume to fetch Skillset, location, experience etc. All resume might have different format, Once parsed I will use those firlds to index via Solr, any help please?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you hit problems? What didn't work?

Comment: I tried with below program.

Comment: I parsed  resume using below    

     Scanner skillsetFile = new Scanner(new File("C:/skillset.txt"));
       ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
       Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
          BodyContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
          Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
       String content = null;
          List arrayList = new ArrayList();
          FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
       parser.parse(inputstream, contenthandler, metadata, pcontext);

Comment: String[] contentArray = content.split("\\s");
          String first = contentArray[0];
          contentArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(contentArray,1,contentArray.length);         
          StringBuffer phrase = new StringBuffer(content);
          int position = -1;          
           arrayList = Arrays.asList(contentArray);
             while(skillsetFile.hasNext() && position==-1){
               String line = skillsetFile.nextLine();
                 for (String word : line.split("[ˆa-zA-Z]+")){
                   position = arrayList.indexOf(line);
             }
          }

Comment: In skillset.txt I have all words like "Skillset", "Programming lanuage", "TechnicalSkills" which a candidate can specify in his resume.wever how will I extract the fields, which I will have to index and search through Solr, because in Solr I will define my field's like below in schema.xml

  <field name="skillSet" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

Here skillset is column name of DB, but how will I extract Data